# Kivy: View live log in app

Tags: python, logging, widget, kivy, textinput

I want to be able to display the kivy logger live in a read only `TextInput` widget, is this possible?

Currently I just have all of my widgets updating a `TextInput` widget with whatever information I give it, but this is a bit clunky and i'm not catching any of the kivy logging.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can use [Watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/)

Comment: @JohnAnderson Ahh, didn't know this existed, that should work :) I'll report back if/when I get it going

Comment: Did you figure something out for this?